# Javascript function parameter for object key

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have made a search `function` that will `return` the `value` for the `key` `id` if the `value` in `name` matches my `key` `parameter`.

```html
function search(array, key){
    for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].name === key) {
            return array[i].id;
        }
    }
 }
```

I am trying to modify the code so I can insert the 'name' `key` and 'id' `key` as modifiable `parameters`. Here is the code I have made to 'achieve' this, but it seems like `object` `keys` cannot be `function` `parameters`?

```html
function search(array, key, compareKey, valueKey){
for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i].[compareKey] === key) {
        return array[i].[valueKey];
    }
}
 }
```

Note: I primarily use this `function` nested in another `for loop` that iterates through data and modifies values and outputs them into another `spreadsheet`. this function lets me iterate through data in another sheet, match values, and output the matched value to the correct row in the output spreadsheet.

Any suggestions on what I can do so I can modify the object's keys on the fly?

solution (I had to remove the '.'):

```html
function search(array, key, compareKey, valueKey){
for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i][compareKey] === key) {
        return array[i][valueKey];
    }
}
```

}

Comment: array[i][compareKey] ?

Comment: wow... yeah, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use square brackets for this:

```
function search(array, key, compareKey, valueKey){
    for (var i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i][compareKey] === key) {
            return array[i][valueKey];
        }
    }
}
```